# Multiple instantiation points with different instantiations?

Tags: c++

I have some code with multiple instantiation points, in which Stroustrup C++ states "A program is illegal if it is possible to construct two different meanings by choosing different points of instantiation. That is, if the bindings of a dependent or a nondependent name can differ, the program is illegal. ".

Does anyone know why the compiler is not catching this?

Thanks

```
void f(int) {}

namespace N {
    class X { };
    char g(X,int) {return 0;}
}

template<typename T> char ff(T t, double d)
{
    f(d); // f is bound to f(int)
    return g(t,d); // g might be bound to g(X,int)
}
auto x1 = ff(N::X{},double{1.1});

namespace N {
    char g(X,double) {return 0;}
}

auto x2 = ff(N::X{},double{2.2});

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -pedantic -Wall -std=c++11 test188.cc && ./a.out

Compilation finished at Tue Jul 21 18:48:29
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know why the compiler is not catching this?

From [[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8):

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template, or of a member function or static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation. A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. **If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.**

a program which violates this rule is ill-formed, but *with no diagnostic required*. Thus, a compiler implementation is not required to flag such an ill-formed program by means of a compiler error.

Comment: I imagine issues occur with this frequently depending on where the template is instantiated especially in large code bases.

Comment: @notaorb Likely, indeed. [CWG issue 993](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#993) added that the end of the translation unit is a point of instantiation so that implementers could make the quite straightforward choice of always deferring instantiations to the end of the TU’s, and not having to bother (_no diagnostic required_) about whether the program is actually ill-formed due to an uncareful developer. My experience is that both Clang and GCC make use of this approach.

Comment: I tested and this particular code binds `g(X,double)` for both `x1` and `x2`.  This leads me to believe that the point of instantiation is at the end of the TU opposed to where the template function is called.  This differs from what Stroustrup states in C++ 4th Ed Page 752.  Do you know if some change was made to the standard (I'm using std=c++11) or the compiler for this?

Comment: @notaorb CWG issue 993 was accepted in time for C++11, but this only opened up the _choice_ for compiler implementers to decide what point of instantiation to actually make use of. It’s possible that earlier compiler versions of gcc and/or clang did not always make the end of TU choice for these kind of instantiations, and that Stroustrup used one of these older compilers when compiling his example. If you are curious, you could always inspect the result for older gcc and clang versions at Wandbox, knowing however that you are trying to reason with undefined or ...

Comment: ... implementation-defined (whilst ill-formed) behaviour, at best, a practice that is usually quite futile, beyond non-logical curiosity.